# SQL - CASE statement with Group By function

Tags: sql

I wrote this query and trying to also group by "D" but it is not working. Any help??

```
(select hr_id, max(delivery_dt)as maxd,
  (CASE 
    WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2010' then '< 6 MO'
    WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2004' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-may-2010'   then '7 - 78 MO'
    WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-nov-1999' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-april-2004' then '79 - 132 MO'
    ELSE '> 133 MO' END) D
from INDIVIDUAL_VE_TB 
where hr_id in (select distinct hr_id from MODEL_SC_TB b where b.model_id='200')
Group by hr_id)
```

i got this result

```
HR                DATE               D
2000001076        4/22/1994         > 133 MO
2000004986        12/13/2004        7 - 78 MO
2000003382        12/13/2003        7 - 78 MO
```

this is grouping by HR, i am also trying to group by D but it is not working 
I added D to the group by 
Group by hr_id, D

Any help would be great!!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are not grouping by `D`: `Group by hr_id`

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
Select hr_id, max(maxd), D
from
    (select hr_id, max(delivery_dt)as maxd,
      (CASE 
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2010' then '< 6 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2004' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-may-2010'   then '7 - 78 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-nov-1999' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-april-2004' then '79 - 132 MO'
        ELSE '> 133 MO' END) D
    from INDIVIDUAL_VE_TB 
    where hr_id in (select distinct hr_id from MODEL_SC_TB b where b.model_id='200')
    Group by hr_id)
group by D, hr_id
```

Comment: Still not working. I am getting an error that says not a group by expression.

Comment: You also have to group by hr_id.

Comment: This worked to group by D then HR. Is there away to group by ONLY D??  thank you

Answer (score 1):

The order in which SQL statements are processed is key here:

- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `SELECT`
- `DISTINCT`
- `UNION`
- `EXCEPT`
- `INTERSECT`
- `ORDER BY`

Notice that `GROUP BY` is processed prior to `SELECT`. Therefore, you can't use an alias from the `SELECT` cause - the SQL engine will not know about it at that point. That's also why the other answers that suggested moving it into a sub-select in the `FROM` clause are correct. If it's done in the `FROM`, it will be available by the time you get to the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repeat the whole case-statement in the group. You can't use the alias for that.

If you are using SQL Server you can create a temporary named resultset using the [WITH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) clause and group by that.

If not, you could alternatively create a View without the grouping and group that view by the relevant column.

Version 1 (copy & paste the computed column):

```
select 
    hr_id, 
    max(delivery_dt)as maxd,
    (CASE 
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2010' then '< 6 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2004' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-may-2010'   then '7 - 78 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-nov-1999' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-april-2004' then '79 - 132 MO'
        ELSE '> 133 MO'
    END) D
from 
    INDIVIDUAL_VE_TB 
where hr_id in (select distinct hr_id from MODEL_SC_TB b where b.model_id='200')
group by 
    hr_id,
    (CASE 
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2010' then '< 6 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2004' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-may-2010'   then '7 - 78 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-nov-1999' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-april-2004' then '79 - 132 MO'
        ELSE '> 133 MO' 
    END)
```

Version 2 (WITH clause):

```
with temporary(hr_id, maxd, D)
{
    select 
        hr_id, 
        max(delivery_dt)as maxd,
        (CASE 
            WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2010' then '< 6 MO'
            WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2004' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-may-2010'   then '7 - 78 MO'
            WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-nov-1999' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-april-2004' then '79 - 132 MO'
            ELSE '> 133 MO'
        END) D
    from 
        INDIVIDUAL_VE_TB 
    where hr_id in (select distinct hr_id from MODEL_SC_TB b where b.model_id='200')
    group by 
        hr_id
}
select 
    hr_id,
    MAX(maxd) maxd,
    D
from 
    temporary
group by
    hr_id, D
```

Version 3 is just version 2 in two parts.

Comment: Now it says group function is not allowed here. I am using PL/SQL by the way THX!!!

Answer (score 0):

Move it to a join so you have a groupable expression.

```
select hr_id, max(delivery_dt)as maxd, i.D
from 
  INDIVIDUAL_VE_TB IV1
  join (
    select
      CASE 
        IV2._YOUR_PK_HERE_ PK
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2010' then '< 6 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-may-2004' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-may-2010'   then '7 - 78 MO'
        WHEN max(delivery_dt) > '11-nov-1999' and  max(delivery_dt) < '11-april-2004' then '79 - 132 MO'
        ELSE '> 133 MO' as D
      END
    from
      INVDIVIDUAL_VE_TB IV2
  ) i on i.PK=IV1.PK

where hr_id in (select distinct hr_id from MODEL_SC_TB b where b.model_id='200')
Group by hr_id, I.D
```

Answer (score 0):

`avg`, `sum`, `max` and `count` Functions are not allowed in the `group by` clause, irrespective of what other functions they are within (in this case `CASE`).

Try listing fields in `GROUP BY` you are using in `CASE` condition after `WHEN`, in this case - `delivery_dt`.